# How to set password for grub bootloader?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

How to set password for *grub bootloader* on Ubuntu?

Comment: It is in the help section: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords ?

Answer (score 0):

Username and password are added to the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file. Use your favorite editor and add the following line:

```
password <<username>> <<password>>
```

Example:

```
password john johnP123
```

If you want to add a hashed password, use the *`grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` utility to generate a hashed password. Add this hashed password to the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file like this:

```
password_pbkdf2 <<username>> <<hashed-passwd>>
```

Save the file and run `sudo update-grub`.