# Prevent root from resetting a specific user password

Tags: password

Is there any way to prevent others including root account from resetting a user password?
I'd like to protect my user account not to be logged in by others so that others can't see the mounted encrypted folder.

Comment: Do not just undervote. Please give the reason why or hint.

Comment: i think it's duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/562552/how-do-i-prevent-others-from-resetting-my-admin-password-in-xubuntu-14-04?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually not. I'm just focusing on preventing from changing the password not the encryption and I need a protection from not only user accounts but root. The other questions here seem to only mention from the other user accounts. I'd just like to know whether it is able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you cannot prevent `root` from changing your password. The `root` user has full control of the system, and if someone can log in as `root`, they can change your password. Likewise, if another user has access to `sudo`, you cannot prevent them from changing your password.

You can protect your **data** by encrypting your home folder. Users who can use `sudo` (or log in as `root`) could still change your password, but would not be able to access your data after changing it.

To secure the computer from `root` or other users, you need root access yourself. If you own the computer you should consider:

- disabling the root user (or setting a password only you know)
- ensuring other users cannot use `sudo`
- limiting physical access to the machine when possible
- encrypting the hard drive (usually requires reinstalling Ubuntu).

Comment: Protecting from -viewing- sure. But "root" will be able to delete it, no questions asked.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. It means root can access my encrypted data while I'm mounting the folder with my account via changing my password and log in as my account. So for now, I'll make only my account have manage root. Thanks.